# JSON return empty content

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem,
My JSON does not return content that should return to me according through the OneToMany relation.
It should return the details of my Person object to me but instead return an empty array.
Below is all my code.

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_table")
public class Person implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "person_id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "person_name")
private String name;
@Column(name = "person_lastname")
private String lastname;
@Column(name = "person_details")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private List<PersonDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();

Person(){}

//getters, setters
```

PersonDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_details")
public class PersonDetails implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_details")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "age_person")
private int age;
private String city;
private String country;
private int phoneNumber;
@ManyToOne(fetch =  FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "details_id")
private Person person;

PersonDetails(){}
//getters,setters
```

PersonRespository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>{
}
```

PersonDetailsRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PersonDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetails, Long> {
    List<PersonDetails> getByPersonId(Long id);
}
```

PersonDetailsController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/persons")
public class PersonDetailsController {

PersonRepository personRepository;
PersonDetailsRepository personDetailsRepository;

@Autowired
public PersonDetailsController(PersonDetailsRepository personDetailsRepository, PersonRepository personRepository) {
    this.personDetailsRepository = personDetailsRepository;
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
}


@GetMapping("/{id}/details")
List<PersonDetails> getDetails(@PathVariable Long id){
    return personDetailsRepository.getByPersonId(id);
}

}
```

I skip PersonController.java

My JSON when i go to uri: localhost:8080/api/persons/1/details:

> []

Comment: Your mapping iw wrong. You have two independent associations instead of a bidirectional one-to-many. Read the documentation to know how to properly map such an association: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: @JBNizet could you say so quickly what needs to be improved? I promise that later I will read the link you sent me

Comment: I already told you. The mapping of your one-to-many association is wrong. That's what needs to be fixed (not improved, fixed).

Comment: can you show me only fixed code?

Comment: I posted a link which has explanations and an example of how to map a bidirectional one-to-many association. Read the explanations, and the example. Fix your code accordingly. What's the point of repeating the explanations here?

Comment: I read it and fix my code, but it's still not work

Comment: Post your fixed code, post the content of the database (i.e. the rows of the two tables related to the person ID)

Comment: no matter, I've already fixed it, thank you for your help